# How can I classify instances into two categories and then into sub-categories, when the number of features is high?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-trees, random-forests, k-means

I'm working with a problem where I have a lot of variables for different cases of different users. Depending on the values of the different variables of a concrete user in a concrete case, the algorithm must classify that user in that case as:

- Positive
- Negative

But if the user is classified as positive, it must be classified as:

- Positive normal
- Positive high
- Positive extra-high

If a case is positive, depending on the values of a part of the parameters, we know that the probability to be, for example, *positive normal* is bigger or lower.

To sum up, I see the problem as a spam detector with different spam types.

May this work if I apply an algorithm like:

- Random Forest
- Decision Tree

Or maybe I can include the negative case as a new group and then implement a K-means algorithm? Maybe this would help to find new groups of parameters that will say that the concrete case forms part of a group for sure.

Which one will fit best with a lot of parameters?

Comment: why don't you just use 4 classes in your random forest classifier?
-high positive
-normal positive
-extra high positive
-negative

Comment: @Lustwelpintje Is  random forest the classifier that could obtain the most success cases ?

Comment: Depending on the data and complexity.. I have had some really nice results with a simple random forest. I do believe a neural network can classify more complex functions better than a random forest, but it takes more time to get it right.

Comment: @Lustwelpintje what about Pytorch, could be a good option ?

Comment: Although I have not used it yet, From what I heard Pytorch will also be fine.